# WP7 cordova example does not work

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I did all steps from phonegap.com/start to deploy to windows phone. When i debug default cordoba-1.7.0-Start project on my emulator is only black background nothing is visible when i run this app, but in console output i have info that app was launched and terminated :( What is wrong ?

```
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\mscorlib.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Windows.RuntimeHost.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Windows.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Net.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Core.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Xml.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\3B9113DD-7B84-4DC5-B767-33D200A5DC5B\Install\Cordova-1.7.0-Starter1.dll', Symbols loaded. 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Phone.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\3B9113DD-7B84-4DC5-B767-33D200A5DC5B\Install\WP7CordovaClassLib.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Xml.Linq.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll' 
Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID :: 000348be-f5cf-45c6-a4c0-7e6dce0244c6 
Writing data for /app/www\cordova-1.7.0.js and length = 117960 
Writing data for /app/www\index.html and length = 1100 
Writing data for /app/www\master.css and length = 322 
GapBrowser_Navigating to :: /app/www/index.html 
GapBrowser_Navigated :: /app/www/index.html 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.ServiceModel.Web.dll' 
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.ServiceModel.dll' 
ScriptNotify :: Info:document.addEventListener event named DOMContentLoaded 
ScriptNotify :: Info:document.addEventListener event named deviceready 
ScriptNotify :: Info:Installing capture 
The thread '' (0xfcd0042) has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
Log:"GotDeviceInfo :: 7.10.7720" 
The thread '' (0xf1a0046) has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
The thread '' (0xe010036) has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
Log:"onDeviceReady. You should see this message in Visual Studio's output window." 
The thread '' (0xf6a005e) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver. I assume that you got an error message on first start of the emulator that your graphic adapter isn't capable for all functions the emulator

If your graphic adapter does not fully support DirectX 10 or doesn't has a WDDM 1.1 driver you will only see a dark screen instead of the rendered webpage. This also affects all controls using MultiScaleImage, including the webbrowser control. As far as I know there is no solution for this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The app does appear to be loading, can you post the html that you are running?

BTW: Messages like this: The thread '' (0xf6a005e) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Don't actually mean that the app exited, these are threads being exited, you can hide these messages in Visual Studio's settings.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">


        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        // once the device ready event fires, you can safely do your thing! -jm
        function onDeviceReady()
        {
            document.getElementById("welcomeMsg").innerHTML += "Cordova is ready! version=" + window.device.cordova;
            console.log("onDeviceReady. You should see this message in Visual Studio's output window.");

        }

      </script>




  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Cordova</h1>
    <div id="welcomeMsg"></div>
  </body>